# Test cases in Jasmine

Tags: testing, jasmine

In NUnit (and others) you can stack up test cases using attributes which can be a convenient way to supply different data values to the same test template.

JavaScript obviously does not have attributes, but does Jasmine support a similar concept to these test cases?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jasmine-every](https://github.com/Jon-Biz/jasmine-every), a helper function for Jasmine to allow one to iterate a test or suite through an array of test case data.